# drop of mysql connection on heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

Thanks first of all to those who read me and try to help me. I also apologize for the bad form of expression, but I use Google Translator to be able to express my problem.

My name is Moreno, 68 years old from Italy, passionate about programming and always involved in volunteering for non-profit associations.

I developed a web application spa for the parish using Angular as frontend, Nodejs as backend and Mysql as database. To manage the test phase, I deployed the frontend in Vercel and the backend in Heroku using the repositories on Github. Everything has been concluded correctly and I am able to operate, even with good times remotely. Operating I found, however, after a few minutes of connection, a malfunction and I am notified of the connection failure on mysql.

I also report the code in db.js for the database connection.

In the backend deployment phase I used it as a resource to connect Mysql to the ClearDB backend, but I didn't encounter any problems.

I have submitted a request for assistance to Heroku, but they have replied that it is not their responsibility.

[image]

I'm trying to enter the code I use, but it always gives me an error and I can't.
Can you also help me complete my support request in full with the code I use?

---

thank you for the suggestions, but I worked as you said, but an error was always highlighted that prevented posting the code. Now try again to attach screenshots.
I also tried to think about the cause of this malfunction and I think I have identified the problem, however, only from the point of view of intuition. I have no elements to confirm this hypothesis. When deploying on Heroku I used ClearDB as an add-on. I think it is ClearDb that closes my connection. Could that be probable? In case how can I solve the problem?

[image]

config.json

```
{

"host": "eu-cdbr-west-02.cleardb.net",
"user": "b60576bf178464",
"password": "dddd8db2",
"database":"heroku_002b5ddee9750af",
"port":3306,
"dialect": "mysql",
"underscored": 0,
"pool": {
  "max": 5,
  "min": 0,
  "acquire": 30000,
  "idle": 10000
},
 
"secret": "mysecret is zoe",
"expiresIn": 86400, 
"emailFrom": "moreno@tecnomedia.biz",
"smtpOptions": {
    "host": "authsmtp.tecnomedia.biz",
    "port": 25,
    "auth": {
        "user": "moreno@tecnomedia.biz",
        "pass": "MRN2021GSLL"
    },
    "tls": {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
    },
    "secure": false
}

}
```

Comment: hello, there's no image attached. you need to edit your question to attach correctly either the error or a screenshot of the error.

Comment: And when you edit your question, please [post your code and relevant errors as _text_, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). Paste it, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K.